# Can't toggle a button on Index view of .net mvc 4 web application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, razor, toggle

I am trying to toggle a button on my .net mvc 4 application. I am using a Razor view engine. I wish to toggle a button and generate alternating images. If i click a button, it should generate a checked image, and if i click again, it should generate an unchecked image.  I'm stuck on this since yesterday and am unable to make any progress. Could someone point out the mistake in this code. Below is my Index.cshtml file -

```
@using System.Web.Optimization

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar">
    <input type="image" src="/assets/ico/glyphicons_152_check.png" class="img-rounded" id="btn-true" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btn-true').bind("click", function () {
            if ($(this).prop("src", "/assets/ico/glyphicons_152_check.png")) {
                $(this).prop("src", "/assets/ico/glyphicons_153_unchecked.png");
            }
            else if ($(this).prop("src", "/assets/ico/glyphicons_153_unchecked.png")) {
                $(this).prop("src", "/assets/ico/glyphicons_152_check.png");
            }
            $(this).toggleClass("on");
        });
    </script>

    <!-- Le javascript
            ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/bootstrap-affix.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/holder/holder.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js/application.js")
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548645/image-toggle-button-works-only-once?noredirect=1#comment25530426_17548645     This may help you get your if statement correct

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your if statements. You're not comparing the values, but rather, setting them in place. You need something like this instead.

```
if ($(this).prop("src") === "/assets/ico/glyphicons_152_check.png") {
    $(this).prop("src", "/assets/ico/glyphicons_153_unchecked.png");
}
else if ($(this).prop("src") === "/assets/ico/glyphicons_153_unchecked.png") {
    $(this).prop("src", "/assets/ico/glyphicons_152_check.png");
}
```